# Convert Integer date to a string in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Converting  integer dates into string values in TSQL

```
   Declare @Year INT = 2020
   Declare @Quarter TINYINT = 1
```

How to convert into string to show as 2020 Q1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use [`CONCAT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql) because it handles the data type transformations for you.

```
SELECT CONCAT(@Year, ' Q', @Quarter) as QtrString
```

Answer (score 2):

Eric Brandt has a great option.

Adding Another option, if you want to do the data transformations yourself, use:

```
Declare @Year INT = 2020
Declare @Quarter TINYINT = 1

Select CONVERT(varchar(4), @Year) + ' Q' + CONVERT(varchar(4),@Quarter);
```

Answer (score 0):

use datefromparts

```
declare @Year int=2020
declare @Quarter int=1;

select datefromparts(@Year, case when @Quarter=1 then 1 when @Quarter=2 then 4 when @Quarter=3 then 7 when @Quarter=4 then 10 end, 1)
```

output

```
2020-01-01
```